# Can I stop the senator from healing?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

The Senator is a pretty difficult boss to beat. This is made even harder by the fact that once you beat his health down to ~50% he starts glowing green and healing himself. This process will repeat itself several times throughout the fight, though as far as I can tell his regenerative abilities are eventually depleted (I managed to get him down to 20% before he utterly destroyed me).

Is there a way to prematurely end the Senator's health regeneration, or is it merely something I have to play out?

Comment: Seemed to me like it was just part of the sequence, happened to me over and over too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to wait for him to heal up. When the Senator performs his healing move you'll notice the familiar blade mode target on him, however if you tried to cut him from the front or side he will always counter you. The trick is you have to perform the cut from behind him, this will stop him from healing and stun him momentarily.

So in a nutshell: when he starts healing, go behind him, go to blade mode and hit the target.

Comment: I'll be sure to give this a try asap.